# How to display information contextually in PySide?

Tags: python, qt, pyside

I am unsure how to make a panel or widget or -something- which appears when players click on something.

I tried making a widget in Qt Designer and using show()/hide() on it but when I perform show(); hide(); show() the second show statement doesn't work, nothing gets drawn.

I also have the issue that inserting it into a gridLayout causes the entire grid to be split 50/50 between the two - I can't set a maximum size for the panel - and removing the widget from the layout does not change the split back to being 100%.
I've searched stackoverflow but all I can find are suggestions that I should show()/hide() which doesn't seem to work as advertised. Does anyone else have any insight? It seems like something which should be easily do-able.

PS: I don't mind how it looks as long as it's usable. Part of the objectives of the project is to build the game as quickly, and as ugly, as possible.

Edit: Adding test case by request...

```
class GameWindow(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GameWindow, self).__init__()

        # Load ui file.
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        file_ = QtCore.QFile("forms/GameWindow.ui")
        file_.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self = loader.load(file_,self)

        # Add viewport.
        self.viewport = GameViewport(self)
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.viewport, 0, 0)
        self.horizontalScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(self.viewport.update)
        self.verticalScrollBar.valueChanged.connect(self.viewport.update)

        # Add planetDetails
        self.planetDetails = PlanetDetails(None)

        # Show and perform initial draw.    
        self.show()

class GameViewport(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(GameViewport,self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent
    def mousePressEvent(self,event):
        self.parent.planetDetails.set_planet(None)

class PlanetDetails(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self,parent):
        super(PlanetDetails, self).__init__()

        self.parent = parent

        self.planet = None

        # Load ui file.
        loader = QtUiTools.QUiLoader()
        file_ = QtCore.QFile("forms/PlanetDetails.ui")
        file_.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)
        self = loader.load(file_,self)

        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.hide)

    def set_planet(self, planet):
        self.planet = planet
        self.show()
```

I have been unable to get the problem to reproduce in a test-case written without Qt Designer/QML loading however.

Comment: You should paste your "not working" code. Without seeing what you are doing, it is hard to pinpoint the problem. `show/hide` and `QGridLayout` certainly behave as expected.

Comment: Added test case.

If QGridLayout is supposed to behave as it does what should I be using instead of QGridLayout then to get the behavior I require?

Comment: No, I mean `QGridLayout` behaves as you want it to be. With single item it takes the 100%. With more than one it divides according to size policies. I still need the `*.ui` files to run your code and observe, but `self = loader.load(file_,self)` line looks suspicious. You are setting the parent of the widget to itself.

Comment: Yes. The self = loader... bit is the problem. I've had to go back and rethink my design.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem lies in my assignment to 'self'. I seem to have misread the example in the documentation. I'm not entirely sure how to get the correct behavior without losing access to the Qt Designer's features but at least I know where the error is.